# Why am I getting a column header error, instead of using a passed string to filter, in this database query?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017

Apologies and thanks in advance, day 3 of learning Visual Studio and SSMS;

I am trying to retrieve entries from a database that have a matching "Language" value. Instead of receiving the entries back, I am getting an "invalid column header" error that alludes that I have tried to get a column with a particular header, instead of entries that contain a particular value. I am certainly aware that I could have written my query incorrectly, but I don't know enough about this either way to be sure. I do understand that "Language" is a reserved word in SQL, but I think I have used the proper syntax to allow the DB to be built using it. My query is as follows:

```
public List<Exercise> GetExercisesByLanguage(string language)
 {
   using (SqlConnection conn = Connection)
    {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
       {
         cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT ExerciseId, ExerciseName, Language FROM Exercise WHERE [Language] = {language}";
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I hope to have returned the ExerciseId, ExerciseName, and Language of all exercise records that match the {language} parameter passed in.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: If you run the query directly in SSMS, do you get any error: SELECT ExerciseId, ExerciseName, Language FROM Exercise WHERE [Language] = 'AnyLang'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the language parameter inside quotations:

```
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT ExerciseId, ExerciseName, Language FROM Exercise WHERE [Language] = '{language}'";
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. So, is it just that "language" is a reserved word, that it requires special treatment in that instance and not where I am saying "SELECT....Language From...."